# GCC 6.1.0 vs Intel Compiler 15 and Auto Vectorization performance

Tags: performance, gcc, icc, sse2

Is it possible to achieve similar level of performance in GCC in terms of SSE2/AVX?

It looks like Intel Compiler 15 is superior in auto vectorization efficiency. 
As benchmark I've used classic flops.c benchmark 
(https://github.com/AMDmi3/flops/blob/master/flops.c)

And here are results for my Intel Xeon E5-2690 (Sandy Bridge)

Intel Compiler 15 [ /O2 /arch:AVX /fp:fast ]

```
FLOPS C Program (double Precision), V2.0 18 Dec 1992

Module     Error        RunTime      MFLOPS
                        (usec)
 1    -2.5613e-010      0.0034   4177.1562
 2    -1.4166e-013      0.0058   1209.1768
 3     3.1904e-010      0.0011  15487.5445
 4     9.0594e-014      0.0011  14065.9341
 5    -6.2284e-014      0.0034   8652.6807
 6     3.3640e-014      0.0021  13994.3450
 7     9.4360e-012      0.0101   1193.4732
 8     3.7637e-014      0.0022  13677.6492

Iterations      =  512000000
NullTime (usec) =     0.0000
MFLOPS(1)       =  1730.8542
MFLOPS(2)       =  2971.1755
MFLOPS(3)       =  6296.4960
MFLOPS(4)       = 14153.0984
```

GCC 6.1.0 [ -m32 -mavx -Ofast ]

```
FLOPS C Program (double Precision), V2.0 18 Dec 1992

Module     Error        RunTime      MFLOPS
                        (usec)
 1     1.8119e-013      0.0034   4177.1562
 2    -1.4166e-013      0.0055   1283.6676
 3     8.2157e-015      0.0013  13600.0000
 4     1.8874e-015      0.0023   6655.1127
 5    -2.7645e-014      0.0048   6060.4082
 6     5.1903e-014      0.0041   7159.1128
 7    -8.4583e-011      0.0200    598.5387
 8    -1.4488e-014      0.0041   7293.4473

Iterations      =  512000000
NullTime (usec) =     0.0000
MFLOPS(1)       =  1823.5616
MFLOPS(2)       =  1585.2039
MFLOPS(3)       =  3663.4158
MFLOPS(4)       =  7799.1296
```

Something tells me that I forgot to enable some special switch in GCC.

Ps. Yes I know that Intel Compiler has reduced precision.

Comment: how about `--ffast-math`?

Comment: No real change. MFLOPS(4) went up from 7799 to 7817.

Comment: Intel's compiler is extremely well-known for being able to generate fast, highly-optimized code. It is unlikely that there is a magic compiler switch that will get GCC to achieve the same performance. You will have to resort to hand-optimized use of intrinsics.

Comment: However, this may not just be a reflection of Intel's superior optimizer. It is possible that Intel's high-performance math libraries are playing a part here, too. The [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) is available for download, and supported by GCC, but you will have to write code that explicitly uses the functions it provides. I'm not aware of any way to make GCC do that implicitly.

Comment: Does Intel's compiler compile in 32 bits by default? Otherwise the -m32 is weird. Why try it on some random benchmark instead of your actual program?

Comment: -m64 changes nothing. I've checked that. Yes I like that benchmark.

Comment: try `-funroll-loops`.

Comment: It would be interesting to look at the assembly e.g. of Module 4 of both compilers.

Comment: It might also be worth looking into timing. All those tests are finishing in less than 50 ns. When I benchmark I usually aim for at least a second.  This code goes back to 1992 and supports the Amiga!

Comment: What OS are you testing on? ICC on Windows and GCC on Linux? Do you dual boot?

Comment: -funroll-loops does not change anything. I'm using ICC and GCC on Windows 7.

Comment: How do you use GCC on Windows? E.g. are you using MinGW or MinGW-w64?

Comment: mingw-w64\i686-6.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1

Comment: Try `-march=native` instead of `-mavx` (Intel sometimes generates several versions of the code for several architectures).